# LCD Programming with Arduino

Tags: arduino, lcd, i2c

I'm trying to get my LCD to display "Voltage= (variable)". I have it programmed to write the text and I have a pot wired to my arduino and I'm trying to get a voltage number to come after the equals sign.  How can I program it so when I turn the pot that the actual voltage will come after "Voltage="?

Here's my program

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  
void setup()
{
}
void loop()
{
lcd.init();                      
lcd.backlight();
int sensorPin = A0;
int sensorValue = 0;
sensorValue = 0.004882812 * analogRead(sensorPin) + 1;
lcd.print("Voltage=");
lcd.print(sensorValue);
}
```

Comment: Who voted to close? Why?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - When this question started out, it was in pretty poor shape.  It looks a good deal better now.  Still, if the reason isn't obvious, whoever's voting to close should leave a comment so the OP can fix the question. (Obviously, it wasn't me, as I can't cast an ordinary close vote.)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I ended up with.

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);  

void setup() {}

void loop()
{ lcd.init();                      
lcd.backlight();

int VoltsInput = A0;
int VoltsRange = 0;
int VoltsPercent = 0;

VoltsRange = (5.0/1023.0) * analogRead(VoltsInput);
VoltsPercent = (((5.0/1023.0) * analogRead(VoltsInput)) / 5) * 100;

lcd.print(VoltsRange);
lcd.print("V    ");

lcd.print(VoltsPercent);
lcd.print("%");}
```

Comment: You may want to accept either answer so that we know the problem is solved. (you can accept your own answer, it just doesn't get you reputation)

Comment: Another option is to have decimal point Change: int VoltsRange = 0; To: Float VoltsRange = 0; Get more accurate voltage after decimal point.

Comment: This is more a different approach than a solution to the original question. Its not likely that this will help anyone in the future because it doesn't even state what was wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

So the Arduino's ADC is 10-bits resolution, this means that analogRead will return a value between 0 and 1023 (2^10-1).  You need to re-scale this to the range 0v - 5v.

You can do this simply by dividing by 1023, and multiplying by 5. I'm not totally familiar with the Arduino language, but I hear that it's quite like C. So this should probably work.

```
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27,16,2);

void setup()
{
    lcd.init();
    lcd.backlight();
    int sensorPin = A0;
    float sensorValue = 0;
    sensorValue = (5.0/1024.0) * analogRead(sensorPin);

    lcd.print("Voltage=") + sensorValue;
}

void loop() { }
```

Comment: Take care if you are running on 3V3, or are using a voltage reference (aref), one may be internal and can help to increase resolution on your reading.

Comment: Hi, Rocketmagnet, thanks for the code.  I typed it in and I only get "Voltage=" to come up on the screen.  I'm not familiar with Arduino.  We've been learning to program the 68HC11 chip for this whole semester and then last week our professor throws the Arduino at us and tells us to develop a program for this by next week.  Needless to say this is proving to be a little challenging.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Try [this code](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/PrintFloats) for converting float to string. Where it says Serial.print, change it to LCD.print

Comment: Hi, Rocketmagnet, I finally figured out a code that would let the pot work and I could change the digits on the screen by turning it.  Unfortunately because it's in a loop, the whole screen is either filled with all 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, or 5s depending what the pot is set on.  Is there any way that I can get the results of what's in a loop outside of a loop?

Thanks,

Comment: I updated my code on my original question.

Comment: I guess I should explain why I have it in a loop.  If it's not on a loop then a number will pop on the screen.  The number that pops up is where the pot is set on and when I go to turn the pot, the number on the screen does not change since it's not in a loop to continuously scan for new data.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet - What do you expect to happen from `lcd.print("Voltage=") + sensorValue;` ?  I'd expect the function call to return a number, which would get added to sensorValue, and then not assigned to anything.  Instead, you want to do `lcd.print("Voltage="); \n lcd.print(sensorValue, DEC);`

Comment: Hey, Rocketmagnet, I finally figured it out!  But I could not have done it without your help with the math on the sensorValue!  Thanks, man!

Comment: I had to post my final answer where my original code was located since I can't answer my own question until 8 hours after I first posted it.

Comment: Yes, Kevin, you were right but I'm not sure what "DEC" means.  Does it mean decrement?

Comment: @KevinVermeer - That's exactly what I thought. The OP's original question had this code. I thought it was strange, but I don't know enough about Arduino C to know if it's actually legit. I assumed that the OP original code worked, but printed the wrong value.

Comment: @Eduardo - Check the documentation: http://arduino.cc/it/Reference/LiquidCrystalPrint  It's a definition in LiquidCrystal that causes that call to lcd.print to display its first argument in base 10 rather than hex or as a character.

Comment: `lcd.print("Voltage=") + sensorValue;` would add `sensorValue` to the return value of `lcd.print()`. So this is far from correct.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet the arduino language is C++ compiled with gcc-avr. The environment just adds in some standard headers and `int main() { setup(); while(true) loop(); }` before compiling.